# Bibliography in ConTeXt

Tags: bibliographies, context, context-mkiv

I have two problems with bibliography using `ConTeXt  ver: 2013.01.10 01:04 MKIV`.

1. I would like to get `\citet` like behaviour `Author name [1]`. However, presently the MWE produces only the numbers.
2. Secondly, a list of publications is not being produced at all either `\placepublications` or `\completepublications`.

**MWE**

```
\setupbibtex[database={bib}]
%\setuppublications[alternative=]

\starttext
  I am refering to \cite{me13}.
  \placepublications[criterium=text]
\stoptext
```

**bib.bib**

```
@article{me13,
        title = {This bibliography in context},
        author = {Convert, Recent},
        journal = {Tex SX},
        volume = {1},
        number = {1},
        pages = {1-11},
        year = {2013},
}
```

Comment: The scheme `Author [number]` is not supported by default. But `alternative=apa` is quite close. It displays the author name(s) and the year. I get a list of publications with `\placepublications[criterium=text]` and with `\completepublications[criterium=text]`

Comment: @Marco Did you get the list of publications for this MWE? The workflow is: `context main.tex`. As I understand it, I do not have to run `bibtex`.

Comment: @Marco Issue resolved. However, could you point me a direction on how to go about writing a new bibliography style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `refcommand` to `authornum`, i.e.,

```
\setuppublications[alternative=num, refcommand=authornum]
```

A complete MWE:

```
\setupbibtex[database={bib}]
\setuppublications[alternative=num, refcommand=authornum]

\starttext
I am refering to \cite{me13}.

\placepublications[criterium=text]
\stoptext
```

gives

[image]

**EDIT**: There is a bug with `authornum` due to which it does not work when the citation contains more than three authors. Here is a bug fix.

```
\setupbibtex[database={bib}]
\setuppublications[alternative=num, refcommand=authornum]

\unprotected\def\dobibauthornumref#1%
 {\bibinsertrefsep
  \doifbibreferencefoundelse{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \cite[left=,right=,alternative=author][#1]%
     \bibalternative\c!inbetween
     \cite[num][#1]%
     \endgroup}
    {}}

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=3mm]
I am refering to \cite[me13]. I can also refer to \cite[me13a,me13b].

\placepublications[criterium=text]
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

where the `bib.bib` file is

```
@article{me13,
        title = {This bibliography in context},
        author = {Convert, Recent and User, Latex and Guru, Old},
        journal = {Tex SX},
        volume = {1},
        number = {1},
        pages = {1-11},
        year = {2013},
}

@article{me13a,
        title = {This bibliography in context},
        author = {Convert, Recent and Guru, Old},
        journal = {Tex SX},
        volume = {1},
        number = {2},
        pages = {12-16},
        year = {2013},
}

@article{me13b,
        title = {This bibliography in context},
        author = {Convert, Recent},
        journal = {Tex SX},
        volume = {1},
        number = {3},
        pages = {17-32},
        year = {2013},
}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: If you add two more authors to the example, then `et al.` should be added in the citation. But it only gives `Convert, [1]`.

Comment: I thought that the solution would involve some use of `\setupcite`.